# Java removing object from hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public Map<Object> map = new HashMap<Object>();


map.add(new Object ("a", "b"));


public class Object {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    public Object(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.a = b;
        this.c = "" + a + b + "";
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }   
}
```

I have a hashmap, basically `Object.getC()` should be a + b in a string.
and in some other class, I need to get the c value and if that hashmap collection index has the exact same c value, it will delete the index:

```
public static void deleteChest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if (data.get(i).getItems().length == 0) {
            Object c = new Object(data.get(i).getA(), data.get(i).getB());
            map.remove(c);
        }
    }
}
```

data hashmap should have the same index number as the map hashmap, so if you're wondering what is it.

Basically, I loop through all data hashmap items (to get the A, B and then match if C is inside the other hashmap (map)).

**Now the question time**

How can I check if an object is contained (exists) or delete it (not by index, but by key)? How can I do this (Example above).

Comment: Please don't call your class `Object`. You won't even know what hit you.

Comment: That's just an example. @SotiriosDelimanolis - But thanks to know.

Comment: Off topic: Using Object as class name is not a very good idea. It is better to not use name of classes already existing in the JDK

Comment: @JonyKale, use `Foo` instead

Comment: Are you sure you are using a HashMap and not a HashSet?

Answer (score 4):

You should define the `equals` and `hashCode` method for your class.

Otherwise you fall back to the default implementation which checks for object identity, i.e. if the two references points to the same memory location instead of pointing to two objects containing the same data.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that Map use key to retrieve value.

`Set<Object> set = new HashSet();`

Then when you are using Set or Map, your class must override `hashcode` and `equals` methods. If the do not do that the Set will not know how to properly compare them, to perform any operation.

This is why when you create a new Object(a,b,c) it set can not find them as it use the default value of hashcode with is not related to type members.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to change the  `public Map<Object> map = new HashMap<Object>();` field to `public Map<String,Foo> map = new HashMap<String,Foo>();` and you should change the name of your class from Object to Foo as 'mre' suggestion.

***Foo Class***

```
public class Foo {

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    public Foo(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.a = b;
        this.c = getKey();
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        return c;
    }   

    public String getKey() {
        return "" + a + b + "";
    }

    @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((a == null) ? 0 : a.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((b == null) ? 0 : b.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((c == null) ? 0 : c.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Foo other = (Foo) obj;
    if (a == null) {
        if (other.a != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!a.equals(other.a))
        return false;
    if (b == null) {
        if (other.b != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!b.equals(other.b))
        return false;
    if (c == null) {
        if (other.c != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!c.equals(other.c))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

and you can add objects in map as follows

```
map.put(new Foo("a", "b").getKey(),new Foo("a", "b"));
```

now you `deleteChest()` method will be like

```
public static void deleteChest() {
        Foo foo = null;  
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            foo =  map.get(new Foo(data.get(i).getA(), data.get(i).getB()).getKey())   
            if( foo != null) {
                map.remove(foo.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
```

hope this will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

First, you code cannot be compiled for several reasons.

1. You called your class `Object`. FYI `java.lang.Object` is a base class for all classes. Since *real* class `Object` belongs to package `java.lang` you do not have to import it and therefore it is always available. I do not understand how compiler can solve this naming collision.
2. Interface `Map` has 2 parameters: `K` for key and `V` for value. Therefre line

`public Map<Object> map = new HashMap<Object>();`

cannot be compiled. Change it to

`public Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();`

Or, better use real parameters instead of `Object`.

1. Map interface has method put that accepts 2 parameters. Therefore the following line cannot be compiled too.

`map.add(new Object ("a", "b"));`

Bottom line if you want to use map that associates groups of string use code like following:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "b");
```

To remove value by key use:

```
map.remove("a");
```

To retrieve value use `String v = map.get("a")`

To retrieve all values use either `map.keySet()` or `map.entrySet()`.

Comment: Let's say I want to have <String, ObjectClass> can I do map.remove(map.get(0).getC()) so it will print the key? 0 = the index

Answer (score 0):

The solution that work for me is:

```
map.remove("key");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if(map.containsKey(key)){
            map.remove(map.get(key));
        }
```